# What makes Java compiler think a parent class cannot stand for its child class

Tags: java

The following code causes error:

```
Class<? extends BaseHandler<?, ?>> aClass = resource.getHandler();
BaseHandler<?, ?> baseHandler       = resource.getHandler();
BaseHandler<?, ?> baseHandler       = (BaseHandler<?, ?>) resource.getHandler();;
```

The first line works.
The second line and the third type forcing conversion has error:

```
Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'java.lang.Class<capture<? extends c.c.BaseHandler<?,?>>>' to 'c.c.BaseHandler<?,?>'
```

This is what I think:
`Class<? extend BaseHandler<?, ?>>` should be a child Class type of BaseHandler. then `baseHandler` should stand for all children class. Why it has that compile error?

Comment: A `java.lang.Class` represents the _class_ itself, not an _instance_ of the class. And it's a final class that inherits directly from `Object`, so it cannot ever be a `BaseHandler`.

Comment: No, basically a `Class` is a thing by itself.  `BaseHandler` probably inherits from `Object` or some other `Handler` class.  It does not inherit from `Class`.

Comment: Another way of saying this is that an object *has-a* class -- you can call `getClass` on any object.  But an object isn't *is-a* class.  That's not the relationship an object has to its class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That code doesn't work for the same reason that

```
Class<Integer> clazz = Integer.class;
Integer i = clazz;
```

doesn't work, namely, that a `Class` is not an instance of the class it represents.